# Expressing a step function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, step-function

Take the interval $I=[0,1]$ and the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ defined as follows:

$$x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k}, \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$$
and $x_0=0$. 
Now, that sequence defines a partition for the interval $I$. Let's define the function $f$ such that $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$ and for all other $x\in I$, if  $x_{i-1}<x\leq x_i$ then $f(x)=x_i$, where $i \in \Bbb{N}$. This funcion should look like this:

[image]

Did I define it correctly? Is there another way to define this function in a more elegant/short way? Bonus points if someone could post a plot of this function where the area "under the curve" is shown!

Edit: Is the area under the function equal to $\frac{1}{2}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In my experience, step functions are defined so as to only take on finitely many values, so I would hesitate to call that a step function

Comment: As for what you seem to intend... your function appears to be the one which takes an input of $0.a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5\dots$ in binary and searches for the left-most occurrence of zero after the decimal point, changes it to a $1$, and truncates all the remaining digits after it.  So, for example it would map $0.11\color{red}{0}1000\dots$ to $0.111$ in binary.  (*interesting to note is that choice of representation issues like $0.011111\dots = 0.10000\dots$ don't seem to matter here since they both map to the same output anyways*).

Comment: The rest looks OK to me, at least in that the function you describe matches the picture you have. As for "Did I define it correctly?" - I'm not sure what you mean. Did you define *what* correctly? If you are asking if your function matches the picture, then yes (except that your picture doesn't have $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$)

Comment: The summation for the area under the curve: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}(1-\frac{1}{2^k})=\sum\frac{1}{2^k}-\sum\frac{1}{4^k}=1-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: ... and the area under the curve is clearly greater than $\frac{1}{2}$ because all sections of the curve lie above the diagonal line $y=x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k}=1-\frac{1}{2^n} \tag 1$$
$$2^n=\frac{1}{1-x_n}$$
$$n=\frac{-\ln(1-x_n)}{\ln(2)} \tag 2$$
Eq.$(2)$ is only valid for the discret values of $x$ defined by Eq.$(1)$.

If we want to extend to continuous $x$ we have to use the celling or the floor functions, respectively noted $\lceil\:\rceil$ and $\lfloor\:\rfloor$ :

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CeilingFunction.html

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html

$$n=\left\lceil{\frac{-\ln(1-x)}{\ln(2)}}\right\rceil=1+\left\lfloor{\frac{-\ln(1-x)}{\ln(2)}}\right\rfloor$$ 
Thus, the equation represented on your graph is :
$$f(x)=1-\frac{1}{2^{1+\left\lfloor{\frac{-\ln(1-x)}{\ln(2)}}\right\rfloor}}$$

[image]

$$A=\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(x_n)(x_n-x_{n-1})$$
$$A = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\left((1-\frac{1}{2^n})-(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}) \right) =\sum_{k=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\frac{1}{2^{n}}$$
$$A = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^n}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^{2n}}=1-\frac13$$
$$\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\frac23$$

[image]